# ExpressRoute, public peering, and Azure SQL

Tags: azure

If I connect to Azure with ExpressRoute, and enable public peering, am I correct in saying that although traffic to Azure SQL will be going via ExpressRoute (from my on-prem location) that the Azure SQL endpoint will still be publicly accessible via the internet?

many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the SQL server will still be accessible over the internet, public peering just ensures that traffic on your network goes down the Express Route, anyone else outside the network can still access it from the internet.

If you want to prevent this you can just setup the SQL firewall to only allow access on you Express Rote IPs.

Answer (score 1):

> am I correct in saying that although traffic to Azure SQL will be
>   going via ExpressRoute (from my on-prem location) that the Azure SQL
>   endpoint will still be publicly accessible via the internet?

If your PC in your **on-prem** network, and want to connect the Azure SQL service **via ExpressRoute**, we should advertise default routes (0.0.0.0/0), and we have to configure your routers to return traffic to Azure through the public peering path. If your PC is **not** in your on-prem network, we connect the Azure SQL service via internet.

If you have advertise default routes (0.0.0.0/0), and **not** configure your routers to return traffic to Azure through the public peering path, we connect the Azure SQL service via the internet.